# Save using Spring Data Jpa and find using JdbcTemplate within same transaction

Tags: spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

[image]

When i comment the line 276, The code in the line 277 is not working. Within the same transaction i am saving via data jpa and querying same table data via jdbctemplate. Please help me how to make it working line277 by commenting the line276.

**saving via data jpa**

[image].

**querying via jdbctemplate**

[image]